# Does Firestore pull documents each time a Fragment is opened?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have an Android food ordering app, where I display the menus of each restaurant to the users. The users can then make orders, which notifies the corresponding restaurant owner. In the app, let's say there are 5 restaurants and 50 food items per each.

Each of the food item is a document and I get the menus using FirestoreRecyclerViewAdapter as such:

```
private void createQueriedRecyclerView(Query query) {
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ModelFoodItem> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ModelFoodItem>()
            .setQuery(query, ModelFoodItem.class)
            .build();  //get query into the adapter

    mMenuAdapter = new FoodAdapter(options, v.getContext());
    mMenuRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewFoods);
    mMenuRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); //just for performance reasons

    mMenuLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mMenuRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mMenuLayoutManager);
    mMenuRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);
    mMenuRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mMenuAdapter.startListening();
}`
```

The users will naturally cycle through each restaurant while they  are searching for something to order. My question is this: Do Firestore pull documents each time the Fragment is opened? If so, I am seriously concerned about the pricing here. The menus only need to be loaded once, is there a way to cache it so I don't invoke document reads each time as user kills and restarts the fragment again with the same menu?

Maybe I should not call MenuAdapter.stopListening() each time a fragment is killed. It would impact performance but would load each menu only once, is that the case?

What is your advice to keep document reads as low as possible and possibly cache the read value so as to not read it again?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firestore client SDK already caches documents for you, so that it will not cost a read if the document was previously read, and will also be available while offline.  Please read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) about this.